# Making it positive semdefinite

Tags: matrices

What conditions( on $a$ and $b$) I need to impose on the following matrix to make it positive semidefinite?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I edited.Thanks.

Comment: Did you try writing out the condition of positive definiteness in terms of a general vector $x=(x_1,x_2)^T$?

Comment: it shows, we need to have $a x_1^2+2bx_1 x_2 ge 0 $

Answer (score 2):

By [Sylvester's criterion](http://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/sylvesters-criterion-for-positive-semidefinite-matrices-i/), $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if all its principal minors have nonnegative determinant, i.e., if $a\ge 0$ and $\det(A)=-b^2\ge 0$, which means $b=0$.

Comment: Just to point it out, this also follows from the observation that we need $ax_1^2+2b x_1 x_2\geq 0$, as Neon observed (consider the case $x_1=0,x_2=-b$).